# Firefox Plugin SDK - getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

i have some problems with my plugin for Firefox.
I created a contextmenu, which works fine. But this function dosen't return the content of the Meta-Tag.

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");
[..]
      onMessage: function () {
        pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
             contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.head.getElementsByTagName('meta'));",
             contentURL: tabs.activeTab.url,
             onMessage: function(metaTags){
                var text= "";
                console.log(metaTags.length);
                for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++){
                    if(metaTags[i].getAttribute("property") == "description"){
                        text = metaTags[i].getAttribute("content");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                console.log(text);
             }
        });
    }
```

console.log(metaTags.length) return undefined. It's a Firefox-SDK problem. Cause the Skript works fine in jsfiddle or greasemonkey.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox Add-on SDK [defaults to an "error" log level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Setting_the_Logging_Level) for add-ons, which prevents `console.log` statements from appearing in the browser console. To fix this, either set `extensions.sdk.console.logLevel` (which changes logging behavior for *all* SDK add-ons) or `extensions.extensionID.sdk.console.logLevel` (where extensionID is your add-on's [Program ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Program_ID)) to "all" or "debug".

Comment: I use "cfx run".
"When you run your add-on using cfx run or cfx test, the global extensions.sdk.console.logLevel preference is automatically set to "info". This means that calls to console.log() will appear in the console output."

Comment: I believe that console output actually shows up in the command-line window where you ran `cfx run`, not the browser console IIRC. Can you check that?

Comment: I press Strg + A. Then i choosed extensions. There i activated the Debug-Mode. So i can see the console.log output in the standard debugging tool from Firefox.

Comment: No :( - other console.log statements appear on the console. The problem is the metaTags.length which returns undefined.